# Restrict AWS security group settings in terraform nested resource

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a `aws_directory_service_directory` resource defined in a service, which creates a [security group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/directory_service_directory#security_group_id) that allows ports 1024-65535 to be accessible from 0.0.0.0/0 and this is getting flagged by security hub because AWS CIS standards do not recommend allowing ingress from 0.0.0.0/0 for TCP port 3389.

My question is on how to restrict some of the rules in the resultant security group that gets created by the `aws_directory_service_directory` resource. How do you [remediate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-cis-controls.html#cis-4.2-remediation) this using terraform on a resource that is a by-product of another?

Comment: Can you share your Terraform that's creating the directory? Ideally it should take the form of a [mcve]. The resource creates quite different directory types that impacts the answer to this so it's useful to see how you've configured it.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Consider the example in the terraform page linked in my description above.

If you scroll down to the Attributes Reference section, you will see that one of the attributes of the AD resource is a security group. The attributes of that security group is what I am trying to modify.

Comment: It looks like there isn't an easy way to change these but https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_getting_started_what_gets_created.html basically says not to worry about it because the domain controllers are meant to be exposed to your whole network and that they can't be exposed to the internet because you can't give it a public IP address. I don't know if that helps you if you have something scanning your security groups and flagging the very wide looking ranges open to everything.

Comment: Yeah. I saw that clause and decided to "Risk-accept"