# aws_directory_service_directory in terraform leaves SG wide-open

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-directory-services

I've built an AD directory with Terraform in AWS but SecurityHub recently pointed out that the SG it created has a bunch of ports wide open with `0.0.0.0/0`. Thankfully, I have it in a VPC for internal subnets only, but this is definitely not a great practice and I'd rather set the SG inbound CIDRs to my local VPC network range. Is that possible to change? I don't see a way to get to the SG, other than get its ID.

This is how I created it:

```
resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "ad" {
  name        = local.ad_hostname
  short_name  = "CORP"
  password    = random_password.ad_admin_password.result
  edition     = "Standard"
  type        = "MicrosoftAD"

  vpc_settings {
    vpc_id     = local.vpc_id
    subnet_ids = slice(local.pvt_subnets, 0, 2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099329/restrict-aws-security-group-settings-in-terraform-nested-resource. Unfortunately, you probably wont be able to change it.

Comment: Ugh! I just hate leaving anything open on `0.0.0.0/0` regardless if private or not. Not sure why they don't let you configure that but understand it's probably more AWS than terraform at this point. I suppose I can change directly or ignore warning in SH.